# Collection and DataTable

Tags: java, primefaces, collections, datatable

I have fonction which return `Collection<List<Produit>>`.

```
    public  Collection<List<Produit>> parProduit(String cat) throws IOException { 

    HashMap<Integer, List<Produit>> legaux = new HashMap<Integer, List<Produit>>();
   ...............

    return new ArrayList<>(legaux.values());

}
```

**My view** :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{listModule.toArray()}" var="entry">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Module" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:dataTable value="#{entry}" var="e">
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="cool : #{entry}" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                </h:column>

            </h:dataTable>
```

In this case i get just all Object of **Collection**:

[image]

I want to know how can i get all properties of each object.

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to get as your output?  Please respond by editing your question.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. In Produit, implement a `toString()` method that returns what you want displayed on the page.
2. Replace `#{entry[0]}` with `#{e}` in the your HTML template on the line where you try to print out `cool : <produit info>`

Comment: when i use `#{e}` i get nothing